# Re-install ssh-keygen on unix/mac

Tags: ssh, osx, key-authentication

Something is wrong with the way my Mac generates ssh keys. This has been the second time where I've created a key with  `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. When I paste the created `id_rsa.pub` to use in a connecting service, it does not work correctly. But when I create it on another machine the same way, the public key works.

My question is how do I uninstall and re-install the key generation tool for Mac? And mac ports is installed if that matters.

Comment: By "paste the created id_rsa.pub", what do you mean? You run `cat id_rsa.pub` in terminal, highlight that, and paste it into the authorized_keys file on the server?

Comment: What do you mean by `.. it does not work correctly`? Are you getting any errors from `ssh` while connecting? Post them so we can help.

Comment: No, no errors. But whenever I generate a key on that server, and take the .pub and place it on another server, such as GIT, it never works. I've generated with passwords and without, same result and only when I generate it on my mac.

Comment: can u pls run 'ssh -V' on both the machines and put the output? Second can you pls tell which machines (OS, version etc) are involved? And which machine-2-machine it works?

Comment: Use `ssh-copy-id` instead of copy/pasting the existing key. Have a look at https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't attempt to uninstall the ssh binaries packaged with OSX, it is asking for trouble. You can use macports or similar to install a side-by-side version in /usr/local/ or /opt/ and run that version instead.

However I do not suspect the OSX binary to be the problem.